# Restrict Hamachi Gateway Scope / Ports

Tags: vpn, firewall, hamachi

A client wants to make a couple of websites intranet-only, but still allow access at about 30 outside locations. Hamachi gateway would work nicely for this, but I do not want those computers to have unfettered access to the rest of the network.

I have tried creating firewall rules on the gateway computer (W7 Pro), restricting the Hamachi executable to only a few IP addresses on the network. These rules won't work, though. I have a feeling since it is relaying traffic for other IP addresses (other Hamachi computers), the firewall doesn't touch it because those IPs aren't bound to a NIC.

Has anyone made something like this work?

Comment: From what I could find out, what I wanted to do wasn't possible. We ended up using client certificates with IIS to authenticate.